# Помогите верифицировать OpenBSD 6.5

Tags: linux, sha256, openbsd

По ссылке https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Download качаю .fs или .iso, там ниже написано что SHA256 суммы могут быть найдены в такой же директории как и установочные файлы, но скачивается только или .fs или .iso больше ничего не скачивается. Я так и не понял как мне верифицировать образы? Подскажите кто знает.

Comment: Смотрите, скачиваете Вы, например, `https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.5/amd64/install65.iso`. Под "same directory as the installation files" в этом случае имеется в виду `https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.5/amd64/`, а конкретно Вам нужен файл `https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.5/amd64/SHA256`

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, да, я уже нашел что можно скачать эти файлы с сигнатурами, но так и не понял как их верифицировать. У меня в debian 10 работает только команда `sha256sum` и она выводит определенную сумму но, нигде не могу найти их что бы сравнить. В файле SHA256.sig суммы отдельных файлов, и нету суммы отдельно для .iso или .fs

Comment: Так Вы посмотрите внимательно. Продолжая мой пример выше - находите в этом файле строчку с "install65.iso" и проверяете, совпадает ли хэш скачавшегося файла с `38d1f8cadd502f1c27bf05c5abde6cc505dd28f3f34f8a941048ff9a54f9f608`

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо вам большое, я не заметил той строчки.